# php mysql add 1 to a value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I'm trying to increase the value in the table by one but I don't really know mysql and I don't know whats wrong. It seems to go through no problem but when I check the database the number hasn't changed. Ive changed it a bit to follow what was said about the quotes but to no joy. Thanks in advance! :)

```
        $con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } else {
        echo "it works!";
    }

    switch ($_POST['found']) {
        case "facebook":
            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `found` SET `number` = '1' WHERE `id` = 'Facebook'");


            break;
```

Comment: You're enclosing column names with `'` rather than `\`` which probably isn't helping

Comment: thanks! I did that and it seems to go through no problem but the number doesn't change (at 0)